# Node js + Mysql : cannot enqueue because of fatal errors

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, server

I'm running a application with node js (more specifically express js) and I save some datas with a mysql client.

It perfectly works for some time with no issue but then all of suddden I get these erros:

> Trace: Cannot enqueue Quit after fatal error.
>       at Protocol._validateEnqueue (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:218:11)
>       at Protocol._enqueue (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:135:13)
>       at Protocol.quit (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:88:23)
>       at PoolConnection.end (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:255:18)
>       at Pool._purgeConnection (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:259:16)
>       at PoolConnection._removeFromPool (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\PoolConnection.js:70:8)
>       at PoolConnection. (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\PoolConnection.js:29:12)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at PoolConnection.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at PoolConnection.Connection._handleProtocolError (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:439:8)
>   Trace: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
>       at Protocol._validateEnqueue (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:218:11)
>       at Protocol._enqueue (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:135:13)
>       at PoolConnection.query (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:214:25)
>       at Object.fetchDatas (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\public\javascripts\twelvebase.js:94:12)
>       at C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\routes\index.js:7:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
>   C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\public\javascripts\twelvebase.js:26
>           throw(message);
>           ^
>
> Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
>       at Protocol._validateEnqueue (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:199:16)
>       at Protocol._enqueue (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:135:13)
>       at PoolConnection.query (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:214:25)
>       at Object.fetchDatas (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\public\javascripts\twelvebase.js:94:12)
>       at C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\routes\index.js:7:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\nodejs\twelve-coiffure\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22

The problem is that I really can't find where the issue comes from in my code, and I don't even know why sometimes in works and sometimes not.

Here is my code to start the database:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dbPool = mysql.createPool({
 connectionLimit: 50,
 waitForConnections: true,
 queueLimit: 0,
 host: '*my host*',
 user: '*me*',
 password: '*my password*',
 database: '*heroku database*',
 wait_timeout:28800,
 connect_timeout:10,
 debug:true
});

dbPool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
 if (err) throw (err);

 var db = connection;

 fetchDatas = function(callback) {

    // openDatabase();

    var servicesFemmes, servicesHommes, products;

    db.query("SELECT * FROM servicesFemmes", function(err, servicesFemmes, fields) {

        if (err) {
            callback(sendError(err));
        } else {

            db.query("SELECT * FROM servicesHommes", function(err, servicesHommes, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(sendError(err));
                } else {
                    db.query("SELECT * FROM produits", function(err, products, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                            callback(sendError(err));
                        } else {
                            db.query("SELECT * FROM carousel", function(err, carousel, fields) {
                                if (err) {
                                    callback(sendError(err));
                                } else {
                                    callback(null, servicesFemmes, servicesHommes, products, carousel);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
}
```

Of course I'm calling fetchDatas() from another file to get all the datas to display.

Comment: You probably want to use a promise library here like what [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) offers because this is already in "callback hell".

Comment: do you ever release the connection so that it can be reused again by the pool? + where does the db object come from? shouldn't that be the connection object instead?

Comment: ok @tadman I'm probably going to use that real soon if I don't find a solution here. I just wanted to keep simple (I had start with sqlite3 but it wasn't compatible with heroku hosting) since it's juste a simple page for a small shop.

Comment: @Johannes Merz well I do release the connection for every other sql functions I use but with this one I have a message that says the connection is already released so I figured out it was already done somewhere else (can't find exactly where). And for the db object yes sorry I'm going to edit the post: I missed the line "var db = connection"

Comment: @ArthurDeschamps Often "keeping it simple" by using low-level tools is a contradiction. Error chaining is often a huge hassle without promises. Are you sure your `sendError` function is doing the right thing?

Comment: @tadman You're right. sendError is just a function that sends the error as a response to the request..

Comment: I hope `sendError` returns the error it's given or that callback is going to eat errors and not report them correctly.

Comment: @ArthurDeschamps maybe the place where the connection gets released is the source of your problem. The actual code you posted looks good to me (besides the releasing stuff).

Comment: Ok @JohannesMerz I will find this piece of code and let you know what's up

Comment: @tadman I finally went with your advice and used Sequelize. That was perfect and solved my issues. Thank you

Comment: Might be worth posting your re-worked code as an answer to help other people in the same jam.

Comment: That's good code, but try and post it as an answer below. When you accept it it marks the question as "solved" automatically. Keeps things organized.

Comment: @tadman ok thanks for the tips ! I hope I did good this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I gave up on plain MYSQL and started using Sequelize instead. Here is my code (which finally works):

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('database name', 'username', 'password', {
host: 'your host url',
dialect: 'mysql',

pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idle: 3000
}
});


//Models' creation
var servicesHommes = sequelize.define('servicesHommes', {
 nom: {
     type: Sequelize.STRING,
     field: 'nom'
 },
 cheveuxLongs: {
     type: Sequelize.STRING,
     field: 'cheveuxLongs'
 },
 cheveuxCourts: {
     type: Sequelize.STRING,
     field: 'cheveuxCourts'
 }
}, {
 freezeTableName: true
});

var servicesFemmes = sequelize.define('servicesFemmes', {
nom: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'nom'
},
cheveuxLongs: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'cheveuxLongs'
},
cheveuxCourts: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'cheveuxCourts'
}
}, {
freezeTableName: true
});

var carousel = sequelize.define('carousel', {
 photo: {
     type: Sequelize.STRING,
     field: 'photo'
 }
});

var produits = sequelize.define('produits', {
  marque: {
     type: Sequelize.STRING,
     field: 'marque'
  },
  nom: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'nom'
  },
  photo: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'photo'
  }
}, {
freezeTableName: true
});

synchronizeBdd = function(callback) {

sequelize.sync().then(function() {
//any function querying the database should be placed here in this callback


    fetchDatas = function(callback) {

        servicesFemmes.findAll().then(function(femmes) {
            servicesHommes.findAll().then(function(hommes) {
                produits.findAll().then(function(products) {
                    carousel.findAll().then(function(carousels) {
                        callback(null, femmes, hommes, products, carousels);
                    })
                })
            })
        });
    }

    //end of sync()
    exports.fetchDatas = fetchDatas;
    callback();
});
}

exports.synchronize = synchronizeBdd;
```

Then I have another file calling my function "synchronize" exported on the last line of previous snippet ("exports.synchronize = synchronizeBdd"):

```
var bdd = require('fileWithSequelizeInstantiation')

bdd.synchronize(function() {
 //here I call the functions related to my database. In my case: bdd.fetchDatas()
})
```

Comment: Don't forget you can use [`Promise.props`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html) to clean up code like you have here. That is useful for running multiple promises in parallel and using their combined results.

Answer (score 0):

For me, i got this error simply because the MySql server wasn't running, so it is a good idea to check that